# how do I make a list of my postings on Wordpress 3.4.2. and theme Twenty Ten

Tags: wordpress, list, indexing

I've tried to find a solution to allow me to make an "Index" of postings I have published (349 posts, 27 pages, 28 categories and 50 tags). 
Is there a simple solution allowing me to display, as a page or post, an "index" of ALL posts, pages, etc. with WordPress?
An "Index Page" where readers and/or subscribers can click on a post/page and be taken to that particular posting.
I've tried various plugins - (Index Press), (Table of Contents Plus) to mention just a couple but, unless I'm doing something wrong, nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=alpha'); ?>
```

This will list all posts in alphabetical order.

More info can be found in the Codex here: [wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Answer (score 0):

[WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is your best friend.

This will give you a list of all posts and pages in the form of links. If you have any additional post types, add the slug to the post_type array.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page')
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>
<?php
endwhile;endif;
?>
```